# DateTime Data Annnotations do not work in ASP.NET Core RC2 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

if I add Data annotations to my ViewModel the value of the DateTime field is always {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}.

**ViewModel**

```
public class EditReleaseViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
        [Display(Name = "ReleaseDate", ResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

The controller is very straightforward, if I remove the data annotation and use the default everything works fine.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EditReleaseViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <label asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ReleaseDate" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

It is an ASP.NET Core MVC RC2 application - perhaps I'm missing something there.

Comment: did you try to use [DataType(DataType.Date)] attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `DateTime` to `DateTime?` in your model.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this on my own way:

Add another data annotation [DataType(DataType.Date)], and then 'Build' the project, and then everything works.

I don't know way but it works for me.

BTW, I'm following the tutorial here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model.html