# Date Format ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to format my date in a form as dd MMM yyyy but I always got the US format mm/dd/yyyy.
I have added the Data annotations in my ViewModel as such as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963064/datetime-data-annnotations-do-not-work-in-asp-net-core-rc2-application) but I still have the issue. I have even tried the former tag helpers (TextBoxFor) with no sucess:

**ViewModel**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
[DisplayName("Date to"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public virtual DateTime? date_to { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<label asp-for="date_to" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.date_to, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Sampling date to" })*@                
                <input type="datetime" asp-for="date_to" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Sampling date to"/>
            </div>
```

Thank you for your help

I am using ASP.Net Core 1.1.0

Sylvain

Comment: DisplayFormat doesn't work for `TextBoxFor` and may be only used in `EditorFor/DisplayFor`

Answer (score 0):

You should use EditorFor, which should render a TextBox by default (if not you can put your own editor in). EditorFor should respect your DataFormatString (TextBoxFor does not).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParseExact()` to get your expected format.

Supposed you have the string `string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time)` in format `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm tt` like `07/05/2017 12:00 PM` then you can do it by,

```
DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0} {1}", Date, Time), 
      "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```